# String Replace issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, replace

I'm trying to replace all instances of a variable in text file using this function

```
public static string GetTextContent(string location, string callbackfromasync)
{
    var markup = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(location);
    var correctString = markup.Replace("callbackUrl", callbackfromasync);
    return File.ReadAllText(correctString);
}
```

I am calling the method like this:

```
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", GetTextContent(GetRegistrationEmailMarkUp, callbackUrl));
```

`GetRegistrationEmailMarkUp` should return a string of HTML.

The markup I'm working with looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/JhM0FA6z).

Why is the string not being replaced?

Comment: please edit your code and place the markup there not in an Image.. thanks if this is your own class / method `UserManager.SendEmailAsync` please show that code as well

Comment: What are the values of `location` and `markup` here? I'd assume the problem is it does not contain the marked replacement string. Also I'm not sure if its such a great idea to get disk access involved in serving http responses like this. How about storing the text in a database? Also someone people are not able to view external resources. Include directly in the question every thing piece of information. The answers to my question might be in there, I have no idea.

Comment: By "GetRegistrationEmailMarkUp simply returns a string of HTML content." did you mean "GetRegistrationEmailMarkUp **should** return a string of HTML content."?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes I should return HTML content. Then `GetTextContent` should also return HTML with some string replaced.

Comment: @hello You have edited your question to match the answer I proposed: are you saying it still doesn't work?

Comment: Works now. Thanks.

Comment: @hello I rolled back your edit because otherwise it would make nonsense of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the operations mixed up. You need to get the data from the file to modify it, not modify the path of the file:

```
string markupFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(location);
string markupTemplate = File.ReadAllText(markupFile);
string modifiedHtml = markupTemplate.Replace("callbackUrl", callbackfromasync);
return modifiedHtml;
```